# How to send mail to selected users

Tags: python, django

Here i have a view which will either sends email to selected users or delete the selected users.The deleting the selected users is working fine but sending email to selected to users is not working. I tried these ways for sending email to selected email.
with first approach

```
Exception Type: AttributeError
Exception Value:    
'str' object has no attribute 'email'
```

and also i want to remove the selected users from session if email sends to the users and restart the session again which is not happening here with this code

With second approach it says `invalid email address`.

First Approach

```
def selected_users(request):
    selected_users = get_user_model().objects.filter(id__in=request.POST.getlist('users'))

#tring to store selected users in session
    initial = {'users':[]}
    session = request.session.get('users',initial)
    if selected_users:
        for user in selected_users:
            session['users'].append(user.email)
            request.session['users'] = session
            print('hello',request.session['users']) # here i want to restart session either email sends or not to the user
    if selected_users and  request.method == 'POST' and 'delete_selected' in request.POST:
            selected_users.delete()
            messages.success(request, 'deleted')
            return redirect('view_users')
    elif request.method == 'POST' and 'mail_selected' in request.POST:
            form = SendMailForm(request.POST or None)
            config = EmailConfiguration.objects.order_by('-date').first()
            backend = EmailBackend(host=config.email_host, port=config.email_port, username=config.email_host_user,
                                   password=config.email_host_password, use_tls=config.email_use_tls)
            if form.is_valid():
                sub = form.cleaned_data['sub']
                msg = form.cleaned_data['msg']
                for user in request.session['users']:
                    email = EmailMessage(subject=sub, body=msg, from_email=config.email_host_user, to=[user.email],
                                             connection=backend)
                    email.send()
                    messages.success(request, 'Your mail sent.')
                    return redirect('view_users')

            return render(request, 'send_mail_selected.html', {'users': selected_users,'form':form})

    else:
            messages.error(request, 'Invalid request')
            return redirect('view_users')
```

second approach

template

```
<form method="POST" >
    {% csrf_token %}
<p><label>To</label> <input type="text" value="{% for user in users %}{{user.email}}{% endfor %}"></p>

<p><label>Subject</label> <input type="text" name="sub" ></p>
<p><label>Message</label> <textarea name="msg" rows="10"></textarea></p>
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="mail_selected">Send </button>

</form>
```

views.py

```
            if form.is_valid():
                sub = form.cleaned_data['sub']
                msg = form.cleaned_data['msg']
                to = form.cleaned_data['to']
                email = EmailMessage(subject=sub, body=msg, from_email=config.email_host_user, to=to,
                                             connection=backend)
                email.send()
                messages.success(request, 'Your mail sent.')
                return redirect('view_users')

            return render(request, 'send_mail_selected.html', {'users': selected_users,'form':form})
```

forms.py

```
class SendMailForm(forms.Form):
    to = forms.EmailField(required=False)
    sub = forms.CharField(max_length=250)
    msg = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've stored the email addresses, not the user objects, in the list. So you should use them directly:

```
for email in request.session['users']:
    email = EmailMessage(subject=sub, body=msg, from_email=config.email_host_user, to=[email], connection=backend)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer.Now it says `Exception Type: SMTPRecipientsRefused
Exception Value: 
{'=?utf-8?q?users?=': (553, b'5.1.2 The recipient address <=?utf-8?q?users?=> is not a valid RFC-5321\n5.1.2 address. a20sm11396565pjs.30 - gsmtp')}`

Comment: You're doing something odd earlier on, with `request.session['users'] = session`. Why are you doing that? Remove that line.